# Webpack 'production' mode compiles nothing

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-5

I followed the typescript guide: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/
When I run webpack with "production" mode, it emitted almost nothing.

Here is the source code of my src/index.ts file:

```js
export function foo() {
  return 'foo'
}
export const bar = 'bar'
```

Then I run the command:

```sh
webpack
```

I got the 'bundle.js' file compiled into the 'dist' folder, the code is:

```js
(()=>{"use strict"})();
```

But if go to the 'src' folder and compile with the 'tsc' command, it generate the javascript file with the following code:

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.bar = exports.foo = void 0;
function foo() {
    return 'foo';
}
exports.foo = foo;
exports.bar = 'bar';
```

I think both 'dist/bundle.js' and the 'src/index.js' file should be the same, at least the functionality. But now 'dist/bundle.js' file doesn't work at all.

And bellow are the code of other related files:

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "webpack-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  }
}
```

```js
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using webpack in `production` mode will drop dead code via [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

`foo` function and `bar` variables are unused export that should be dropped. That is what's known as "dead code".

If you create another file that uses the `bar` variable.

```
import { bar } from "./index";

console.log(bar);
```

The `bundle.js` output will be:

```js
(()=>{"use strict";console.log("bar")})();
```

TypeScript just erases the types and compiles the code to target JavaScript language version such as `es5`, it has no tree-shaking conception.

Comment: Thank you. But if I just want to compile the 'src/index.ts' file to the entry of my module? In another word, I just want to export something out, and use it in some other external modules.

Comment: @hon You probably should compile the entry as a library. See [author-libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#root).  And the `library.type` can be `umd`, so that the bundle can work with CommonJS, AMD, and script tag

Comment: Thank you @slideshowp2, It works, so great!